# What is the entitlement to allow reading of file in a Mac OS X App? (deny file-read-data error)

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, sandbox, file-read

I am making a Mac OS X App (sandboxed) which reads from an installed config file in /etc/myfolder. When I am trying to read the file using NSFileHandle, I am getting the following error in Console:

`sandboxd: ([3251]) MyApp(3251) deny file-read-data /private/etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf`

I have set the following entitlements in my Entitilements file, but I still get denied by sandboxd.

- com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-only
- com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only
- com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only

EDIT: It seems that I have misused

`com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only`.

I set it as a Boolean. I was under the impression that setting it to YES will enable all file reads using absolute paths. The value of the above entitlement must be the absolute path that will be permitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only` and the absolute path `/private/etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf` - the (10.8.3) sandbox doesn't seem to accept the `/etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf` path containing the symbolic link.

*Note*: If you are sandboxing for the Mac App Store you will probably face a near impossible task getting your app accepted with a temporary entitlement to read files in /etc. You would be better off storing this file in your app's container - in the MAS every app is an island surrounded by shark infested waters.

Comment: I am using OS X 10.7.5, and that combination:
/private/etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf with com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only
did not work.

Comment: @MiuMiu - There is no single sandbox especially in 10.7 - just about every point release is different in some way (the sandbox was still being developed). The names of some entitlements even changed I think. This means what works in one may fail in another... Having said that: check the path you are using contains no symbolic links, the best chance of it working is to use an absolutely absolute path! The entitlement is either string-valued or array of string-valued if you need to specify more than one path. Best option remains to move the file to your app's container or turn off the sandbox

Comment: It seems that I have misused "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only". I set it to a Boolean value before. I have now set it to a string which corresponds to the absolute path that will be permitted to be read, and used /private/etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf (using /etc/myfolder/myconfig.conf only does not work). Thanks!